# invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "d"

Tags: postgresql, k-means

As part of the k-means algorithm, I am trying to update the cluster each item belongs to as in the below query. Problem is, I cannot seem to be able to reference table d inside the nested query.

```
UPDATE algorithms.km_crimes d SET cluster_id = c.id 
FROM (SELECT id FROM algorithms.km_cluster_centres c 
ORDER BY |/ (POW(d.latitude-c.latitude,2)+POW(d.longitude-c.longitude,2))      
ASC LIMIT 1) AS c
WHERE d.cluster_id IS DISTINCT FROM c.id;
```

Can anyone suggest how to restructure the query? I've tried too many modifications to count

Comment: The corresponding query in [this article](http://jonisalonen.com/2012/k-means-clustering-in-mysql/) looks like it should work without modification

Comment: @NickBarnes That is the article I based my code on, however I am using GET DIAGNOSTICS num_rows = ROW_COUNT;
to check how many crimes have been allocated to a different cluster and stop k-means when num_rows is 0 (no changes). With the query in the article the count is always equal to the total num of rows

Comment: 1) what is this `|/` operator ? 2) i would suggest a window function (rank() ) and select rank=1, instead of the LIMIT in the subquery. 3) maybe LATERAL ?

Comment: |/ is the square root operator. Thank you for the suggestions everyone :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [MySQL example](http://jonisalonen.com/2012/k-means-clustering-in-mysql/) which you are converting, you don't need to change this first query at all.

The algorithm doesn't care how many times a `cluster_id` is reassigned in each iteration; it just needs to stop when none of the cluster centers are moved. And luckily, the second query is much easier to fix.

This appears to work:

```
CREATE TABLE km_data (id serial, cluster_id int, lat double precision, lng double precision);
CREATE TABLE km_clusters (id serial, lat double precision, lng double precision);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION kmeans(k int) RETURNS VOID LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
BEGIN
  TRUNCATE km_clusters;

  INSERT INTO km_clusters (lat, lng)
  SELECT lat, lng FROM km_data
  ORDER BY random() LIMIT k;

  LOOP
    UPDATE km_data d SET cluster_id = (
      SELECT id FROM km_clusters c 
      ORDER BY |/(POW(d.lat-c.lat,2)+POW(d.lng-c.lng,2)) LIMIT 1
    );

    UPDATE km_clusters c
    SET lat=d.lat, lng=d.lng
    FROM (
      SELECT
        cluster_id, 
        AVG(lat) AS lat,
        AVG(lng) AS lng
      FROM km_data
      GROUP BY cluster_id
    ) d 
    WHERE
      c.id=d.cluster_id AND
      ABS(c.lat-d.lat) < 0.001 AND
      ABS(c.lng-d.lng) < 0.001;

    EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;
  END LOOP;
END $$;
```

You can tune the numbers in the final `WHERE` clause if you want more precision, though this looks like a pretty imprecise algorithm to begin with.

Comment: that's actually a good solution.. problem is it seems to get stuck in an infinite loop. Having this same problem with the code I described in my update too

Comment: It may have had something to do with the floating point comparisons in the convergence criterion. I've tweaked it a bit. Or it might just be slow on larger data sets, I only tried it with six points...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to do it without alias?

```
UPDATE algorithms.km_crimes SET cluster_id = c.id 
FROM (SELECT id FROM algorithms.km_cluster_centres c 
    ORDER BY |/ (POW(algorithms.km_crimes.latitude-c.latitude,2)+POW(algorithms.km_crimes.longitude-c.longitude,2)) ASC LIMIT 1) AS c
    WHERE algorithms.km_crimes.cluster_id IS DISTINCT FROM c.id;
```

Comment: ERROR:  invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "d"
LINE 3:         ORDER BY |/ (POW(d.latitude-c.latitude,2)+POW(d.long...
                                 ^
HINT:  There is an entry for table "d", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.

Comment: I think the problem is, that you use the algorythms.km_crimes inside the subquery, which is a different scope. I don't know your relations, but is it possible to make a join  on the algorithms.km_crimes inside the subquery?